# Not getting expected results from fetch() - Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Still kinda new to this, I've managed this successfully with 3-4 other websites without too many problems, but now I've hit a wall.

This is the code:

```
const fetch = require('isomorphic-fetch');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

const getSilph = async () => {
  const req = await fetch('https://thesilphroad.com/card/u/Liiiaaam93');
  const data = await req.text();
  const $ = cheerio.load(data);
  const arena = $('#networkAndAchievements');

  console.log(arena);
}
getSilph();
```

I've tried with a bunch of different selectors with no luck, i just get the same results...
the terminal output is:

```
initialize {
  '0': <ref *1> Node {
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'div',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] { id: 'networkAndAchievements' },
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { id: undefined },
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { id: undefined },
    children: [
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node]
    ],
    parent: Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [Array],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Node]
    },
    prev: Node {
      type: 'text',
      data: '\n        ',
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Circular *1]
    },
    next: Node {
      type: 'text',
      data: '\n        ',
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Circular *1],
      next: [Node]
    }
  },
  length: 1,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *2> initialize {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *2> initialize {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  }
}
```

Not sure what the output is actually showing me, and didn't really know what to search for.

Comment: Do you see any console errors?

Comment: I have tried to run the code which you provided and can see the different result from yours.

Comment: The result looks like 
```initialize {
  '0': <ref *1> Node {
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'div',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] { id: 'networkAndAchievements' },
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { id: undefined },
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { id: undefined },
    children: [
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node], [Node],
      [Node]
    ] ,........
```

Comment: ah yeah, the result i posted was from a more specific selector - ('#networkAndAchievements > div.arenaHistory.cardBlock > div.content > div.display.bouts.selected') 
But still not sure how to get my desired results.

Comment: There is no `div.display.bouts.selected` in the HTML source so you are getting an object that represents 'no result'. If you were to do `console.log(arena.html(), arena.length)` you'd get `null, 0`. It's not very clear to me what your question is & consider updating your question (at least with the actual selector that produces that log output!). Edit: Do whatever you can to _help people that are trying to help you_ by [making a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: updated main post, my question is:
why aren't i getting the expected results and what are the results that i am getting.
i copied the `div.display.bouts.selected` selector using chrome dev tools > copy selector

EDIT: However `console.log(arena.html()); ` instead of   `console.log(arena);` works!

Comment: Logging `arena` just logs the `cheerio` object (not the html that was loaded). As you found out you have to call certain functions to get the various parts of the dom. Eg calljng `html()` on the `cheerio` object to get the html text, or `attr('attributeName')` to get the value of an attribute on that element.